# Input element not being updated after model attribute changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use buttons to append to input element a value. Although model variable is updated the input value remains the same. How to fix it?

```
<input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           id="inputSecurityCode"
                           style="width: 100%"
                           placeholder="4 digits"
                           name="inputSecurityCode"
                           ng-model="reservation.securityCode"
                           ng-pattern="patterns.securityCode"
                           ng-focus="focused('inputSecurityCode')"
                           ng-blur="blurred('inputSecurityCode')"
                            />
<button type="button" ng-click="numButtonClick(1)">1</button>
```

**AngularJS**

```
    $scope.reservation = {
            securityCode: undefined
        };

    $scope.numButtonClick = function(num){
                switch($scope.focusedInput){
                    case 'inputSecurityCode':
                        $scope.reservation.securityCode += num;
                        break;
                }

        };
$scope.patterns = { 
                        securityCode : /^[0-9]{4}$/
    };
```

**UPDATE**

Probably it's because starting value is `undefined`, `NaN` and when trying to NaN plus integer is returning NaN and cannot be added to input. Should it be `null` instead of `undefined`?

**UPDATE 2**

All `undefined` have been changed to `null`s but same behavior observed.

**UPDATE 3**

I found when I remove `ng-pattern="patterns.securityCode"` all works fine. How come?

Comment: you said "model variable is updated". So I guess it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This does not appear to be OP's issue and is probably incorrect information.

It's because changes to an object's primitives properties are not propagated automatically by AngularJS.

Reapply the binding manually like this:

```
$scope.numButtonClick = function(num){
            switch($scope.focusedInput){
                case 'inputSecurityCode':
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                         $scope.reservation.securityCode += num;
                    });
                    break;
            }

    };
```

Comment: I am getting `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`

Comment: I made an edit. Try that. If it doesn't work, the issue will be something else probably.

Comment: does your code work when using $scope.reservationSecurityCode instead of an object reservation with primitive property securityCode ?

Comment: Same error after changing to `$scope.reservationSecurityCode `

Comment: After putting some value into `input` the model variable is not being updated. And after pressing button the existing value is being reset,  `reservationSecurityCode` becomes `undefined`

Comment: you will need to simplify your code further to get to the root cause. put a console.log() in the switch case to be sure it gets hit. Change "$scope.reservationSecurityCode += num;" to "$scope.reservationSecurityCode = 1337". See what complexity you can remove to find out what causes your problem.

Comment: `$scope.reservationSecurityCode` is being updated but not reflected in input although being binded by ng-model directive.....